# I want to login via taking data from JSON file using Java Program

Tags: java, json

this is userInfo.json

```
{
 "userInfo":[
 { "name":"John", "password":"Doe" },
 { "name":"Anna", "password":"Smith" },
 { "name":"Peter","password":"Jones" }
]}
```

this is my portion of java class.

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TomCatServer\\src\\java\\logInfo.json")) {
        //Read JSON file
         JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
         /*JSONObject obj2= (JSONObject) obj.get("address");
         pr.println(obj2.get("city"));*/
         HashMap<String, String> login = new HashMap<String, String>();
         JSONArray logInfo=(JSONArray) obj.get("userInfo"); 

         for(int i=0; i<logInfo.size(); i++)
         {
         String name = (String)(JSONObject) logInfo[i].get("name");\\error here
         String password = (String)(JSONObject) logInfo[i].get("password");
         \\error here when get the password
         login.put(name,password)
        }
```

I am suffering syntax error while parsing name and password from json file.

Comment: logInfo is not a Java array. So you can use `[]` to access its elements. Look at the javadoc of JSONArray to discover which methods it has.

Answer (score 0):

The much cleaner way to read your JSON file is to make use of `ObjectMapper` class of jackson json library.

Ref to [sample tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html#read-object-from-json-file) and understand how you can include Jackson library in your code base.

In short, you will be creating a `User` Model class with `name` and `password` as two fields in it. Ideally this piece of code should solve your problem.

```
List<User> myUsers = mapper.readValue(jsonArray, List.class);
```

But your Data structuring isn't straight forward as you have defined redundant `userInfo` in the JSON. If you need to keep that key in your json data, you should also tell jackson to skip the root while parsing the json using below code.

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

If you can change your json file, I would suggest you to restructure it as follows

```
[
 { "name":"John", "password":"Doe" },
 { "name":"Anna", "password":"Smith" },
 { "name":"Peter","password":"Jones" }
]
```

Also read more about jackson at their [github page](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Hope this helps.